# Apache rewrite URL to be caught by AliasMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need mod_rewrite to re-map an incoming url so that it gets caught by AliasMatch.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/app/(.*)  ^/dev-dave/app/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/static/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/static/(.*) ^/dev-dave/static/$1



AliasMatch ^/(.*)/static/(.*)$ /var/www/html/cosmos/$1/dist/static/$2
AliasMatch ^/(.*)/app/(.*)$ /var/www/html/cosmos/$1/dist/index.html
<Directory /var/www/html/cosmos>
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Is this possible? I can't get this to work.

Comment: Does it help if you add `[PT]` flag to your Rewrite Rules

Comment: You are amazing. That was it. If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) :

> If you wish other URL-mapping directives (such as Alias) to be applied
>   to the resulting URL-path, use the [PT] flag as described below.